# Access 365 convert text back to BigInt

Tags: sql, ms-access, office365, bigint

I have an entire process in Access with many queries that was written before BigInt was supported.  There is a table that I had to import because it contained a BigInt field.  Now that I'm on O365, I can work with BigInt, but I don't want to alter all my tables and queries to support BigInt.  Instead, I will create new queries that can compare the text version of the BigInt field that was imported with the actual BigInt in the table now that I can link to it so that I can update the linked table using queries.  The field has up to 17 digits.

I've tried Val(textkey), but that produces scientific notation.  When formated, only shows the left 15 digits and trailing 00.
Cdbl() and Csng() do the same.  CLNG() gives me #Num! errors.  Cdec() gives me an Arguments error).

Comment: I'm trying to save to a new table with Large Number as the data type.  I'm working with 17 digit record IDs and all I can get at the first 15 digits with trailing 00.  Even adding 2 digit numbers to it results in 00 unless it's over 50, then it rounds up to the next hundred.

Comment: Is this a primary key field? If it is an identifier and not a quantity, why not just keep it a text field?

Comment: It's complicated.  It is a Primary Key stored as BigInt on a SQL Server.  Using Access 2013, I built my own set of queries and macros to import the data, analyze it against other data, and provide me with the edits I need to make.  Edits are made using a special "Utility" client.  Now that I have O365, I have the ability to link directly to the table, so I'm trying to modify my tool to automate the edits instead of manually doing it via the Utility.  I have so many queries, transition, and temp tables that I would rather not go through and modify it all to use Large Number for those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *Decimal* or convert to BigInt:

```vb
LongTextNumber = "1234567890123456"

? VBA.CDbl(LongTextNumber)
 1.23456789012346E+15 

? VBA.CLngLng(LongTextNumber)
 1234567890123456 

? VBA.CDec(LongTextNumber)
 1234567890123456
```

To convert to Decimal in a query, use this wrapper:

```vb
Public Function CDec2(ByVal Value As Variant) As Variant

    CDec2 = CDec(Value)

End Function
```

Comment: I need it to be in a SQL query, not in VBA.  Cdbl produces scientific notation.  Changing the format gives me the first 15 of my 17 digit record IDs (12345678901234500).  Adding 2 digit numbers to it results in 00 unless it's over 50, then it rounds up to the next hundred.  Clng gives me #Num! errors.   Cdec gives me a "wrong arguments" error.

Comment: That's an old and stupid bug. See extended answer, please, for a workaround.

Comment: Excellent.  This works except for needing "End Function" instead of "End If".  Now a new question:  How do I create a field of "Large Number" using the Alter Table, Add Column query?  I tried "Long Integer", but it just creates a "Number" type, which isn't compatible.  And "Large Number" is not recognized.  Google search isn't helping, all I'm getting is how to manually add and define a field.

Comment: Nevermind.  It's "BIGINT".  Why are they so inconsistent??  Thanks for your help.  I'd upvote your answer, but I'm too new.

Comment: Should be able to accept answer. Seem to remember you can gain points if you take the Tour and then might be able to make comments and upvote.

Comment: Ah, yes "accept".  Not the same as upvoting.  I should probably take a tour.